# Strange result after Texture Mapping with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, 3d, 2d

1. Step : Find 68 Landmarks on a 2D image (with dlib)
   So i know all 68 Coordinates of each landmark!
2. Create a 3D mask of a generical face (with OpenGL) -> Result [image]

I know all the 3d Coordinates of the face model as well!

3. Now i want to use [this Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17axYo6mKhY) to texture map all triangles from the 2d image to the 3D generic Facemodel

Does anyone know an answer of my problem ? If you need more information just give me a message and i will send you what you need. Thanks everybody!

EDIT: After finding [this tutorial](http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/02-textures/) i changed the size of my picture to get a width and a height which is power of two.
And then a divide all my picture coords (landmarks)with the size:
landmark(x) / height and landmark(y) / width

Picture :
[image]
Result:
[image]

As bigger the width and the height is as better is the image definition!

Comment: First of all try to disable polygon culling. Than we shall see what is happend.

Comment: Do you have an answer on this too? (see picture under edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing looks like you passed all your vertices directly to `glDrawArrays` without any reuse. So each vertex is used for a single triangle in your result, rather than being used in 6 or more triangles in the original picture.

You need to use an element buffer to describe how all your triangles are made up of the vertices you have, and use `glDrawElements` to draw them.

Also note that some of your polygons on the original image are in fact not triangles. You'll probably want to insert additional triangles for those polygons (the inside of the eyes).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I did what you mentioned in your answer. You can see the result above under edit. But whats wrong now? Could you help me again, please?

Comment: Well, your texture coordinates look just wrong... Looks like your CV code doesn't find the right features on the input image? Actually overlaying your triangles in untextured wireframe would help debug it too.

Comment: The coordinates cannot be wrong they were rechecked, the dubugging did not give any answer as well. Is it maybe the coordinate system? That dlib and Opencv do not use the same system?

Comment: well, they _are_ wrong otherwise you'd get the right picture :). it may indeed be a coordinate system issue of the coordinates. But it would help quite a bit if you provided at least the original image you're remapping. The first picture in this post doesn't look like the remapped one!

Comment: There it is. I also reconized that the original image with the landmarks was increased by its size so i gonna check this if this is the problem with the wrong mapping. But if you would have another idea just let me hear;)

Comment: I've quickly plotted the contour back on the source image, and it more or less looks like the vertical coordinate is 2x what it needs to be... I could imagine the source is in -1:1 range, and you've offseted by 1 to give a 0:2 range instead of a 0:1 range. Are you offseting the coordinate? if so you also need to renormalize by dividing it by 2.

Comment: Im not pretty sure if i understood what you mean. Could you just upload a screenshot of this plot, please? No i did not offset anything, as i know. Ok dividing by 2 makes sense, but which coordinates do you mean. The 2d image coords (landmarks) or the 3d coord from the generic model?

Comment: http://imgur.com/m5jJpBu I'm talking about the 2nd coord of the 2d image, what you pass as texture coordinate to your final render

Comment: Sorry for beeing so late. I did what you said but instead of dividing i have to substract the 2nd coords(of the texture) to set them down. But it still looks weird. Do you know something else to improve the current result?

Comment: well, I looked a bit at dlib. It looks like it outputs pixel locations of the source image, and the samples actually do a pyramid_up on the source image too (increasing its size and thereforce the output coordinates). So you need to look closer at what exact math you're doing to those coordinates to convert them to the [0:1] GL expects. Or put it in your question?

Comment: Ok i just took out the methode pyramid_up not changing the coordinates anymore. But the result is even worse. Have a look in Edit. You understand this behavior ?

Comment: How? Don't leave me hanging :p

Comment: http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/02-textures/ look at this link, it will discribe you the whole operation. For my problem i forgot to divide all picture coord with the width and height (Pixel) from the whole picture. ANd the second problem was that i didn´t have a width and height which was a power of 2. After changing all this it works fine (Screenshot of the result in edit) ;)